# Apache ant compiling error: Does not recognize a package

Tags: java, ant

I got this errors when I'm trying to compile a program that use classes and interfaces that are placed in packages.

```
C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\Program\ConvertorValutar>MyAnt.bat

C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\Program\ConvertorValutar>set ANT_HOME=c
\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\apache-ant-1.8.1\

C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\Program\ConvertorValutar>set JAVA_HOME=
:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17

C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\Program\ConvertorValutar>c:\Users\Flori
\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\apache-ant-1.8.1\\bin\ant.bat
Buildfile: C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\Program\ConvertorValutar\bui
d.xml

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\Program\Conver
orValutar\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\Program\Conver
orValutar\build\main

Compile:
    [javac] Compiling 6 source files to C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme
Program\ConvertorValutar\build
    [javac] Note: C:\Users\Florin\Documents\Anul3\PD\Teme\Program\ConvertorValu
ar\src\main\server\CursValutar.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Run:
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: server/CursValutarServer (wrong nam
: main/server/CursValutarServer)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
     [java]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoade
.java:142)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308

     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
     [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.
ava:482)
     [java] Exception in thread "main"
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Even if says BUILD SUCCESSFUL i got error when I'm trying to run a compiled class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyMServer (wrong nam
: main/server/impl/MyMServer)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

The content of build.xml is:

```
<project name="Socket" default="Run" basedir=".">

  <!-- set global properties for this build.dir -->
  <property name="main.class" value="server.CursValutarServer"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="build"/>
  <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
  <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
  <property name="port" value="7999"/>

  <path id="myclasspath">
    <pathelement path="${build.dir}/main"/>
  </path>  

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build.dir directory structure used by compile -->
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/main" />

  </target>


  <target name="Compile" depends="init" description="compile the source " >
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" 
       classpathref="myclasspath"  includeantruntime="false"/>
  </target>


  <target name="Run" depends="Compile"> 
    <java classname="${main.class}" classpathref="myclasspath" fork="true"/>
  </target>

  <target name="Client"> 
    <java classname="client.CursValutarClient" classpathref="myclasspath" fork="true">
      <arg line="${host} ${port}" />
    </java>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're compiling the classes into the directory "build":

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" ..
```

But the classpath is set to "build/main":

```
<path id="myclasspath">
  <pathelement path="${build.dir}/main"/>
</path>
```